# error including bib file in beamer class ppt

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I have a PPT (beamer class) to which I am trying to add a bib file (`main.bib`). I am getting the following error upon running BibTeX

```
I found no \citation commands---while reading file masterthesis.aux
```

As suggested by tex site, I have included `\nocite{*}` before the \bibliography command. This part of my tex code looks like

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{main}
```

At the top of the code, the packages included are as follows: -

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
```

The `\bibliography` command looks suspicious to me since it is appearing in a different color in TexMaker console.

Any Ideas? I am attaching the code as well

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\author{Upendra Pratap Singh}
\title{Transfer Learning}
%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\insertlogo}
%\setbeamercovered{transparent} 
%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
\logo{\includegraphics[height=1.7cm]{logo.png}} 
\institute{Indian Institute of Information Technology, Allahabad} 
\date{\today} 

\subject{Data Analytics and Machine Learning} 
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
%
%\begin{frame}
%\tableofcontents
%\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{andrew_nips.png}
\caption{sample}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Transfer Learning - Psychological Point of View}
\begin{enumerate}
\item The study of dependency of human conduct, learning or performance on prior experience
\item Describes the effect of past learning upon present acquisition
\item Can be partial/complete application or carryover of knowledge/skills
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Transfer Learning versus Traditional Machine Learning paradigm}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{traditional_ml.png}
\caption{Traditional Machine Learning Paradigm}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Transfer Learning versus Traditional Machine Learning paradigm}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{transfer_learning_paradigm.png}
\caption{Transfer Learning Paradigm}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Transfer Learning - Psychological Point of View}
Types of Transfer Learning
\begin{enumerate}
\item Positive transfer
\item Negative transfer
\item Neutral transfer
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Transfer Learning - Psychological Point of View}
Theories of Transfer Learning
\begin{enumerate}
\item Theory of identical elements
\begin{itemize}
\item By E.L. Thorndike
\item Carrying over from one situation to another is roughly proportional to the degree of resemblance of a situation 
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Transfer Learning - Psychological Point of View}
Theories of Transfer Learning
\begin{enumerate}
\item Theory of generalization of experience
\begin{itemize}
\item By Charles Judd
\item Assumes that what is learnt in task A transfers to task B, because in studying task A, the learner develops a general principle which applies in part or completely in both A and B
\item The ability of individuals to generalize knowledge varies with the degree of their intelligence 
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}



\begin{frame}{Transfer Learning - Machine Learning perspective}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{transfer_of_learning.png}
\caption{Transfer Learing - Machine Learning Perspective}
\end{figure}

The ability of a system to recognize and apply knowledge and skills learned in previous domains/tasks to novel tasks/domains which share some commonality.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Transfer Learning - A two-step process}
\begin{enumerate}
\item To identify the commonality between the tasks/domains
\item To transfer knowledge from previous domains to the target domains
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Why Transfer Learning}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Datasets unavailable or expensive to procure
\item Theoretical test data is different from real world test data
\item Real world -messy
\item Each client has individual preferences - thus test data unique
\end{enumerate}
As a result, models frightfully lack the ability to generalize to real world scenarios
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Evolution of Transfer Learning}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Tom Mitchell proposed \textit{bias learning}
\item Neural Nets used for transfer learning
\item Pratt adopted \textit{entropy} measures to assess the quality of hyperplanes
\item Framework developed to use internal representations generated by NNs for tranfer learning problems
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Evolution of Transfer Learning}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textit{Incremental learning} concepts were formulated that result in extreme nested system of learning functions
\item \textit{Multi-Task Learning} proposed 
\item \textit{Covariate shift} coined by Shimodiara
\item \textit{Domain Adaptation} evolved to get rid of limitations of covariate shift
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Evolution of Transfer Learning}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textit{Leave One Out Risk} was overcome
\item Domain adaptation applied intensively to NLP problems
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Transfer Learning Strategies}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{transfer_learning_strategies.png}
\caption{Tranfer Learning Strategies in a Nutshell}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Transfer Learning Strategies}
\begin{enumerate}
\item To correct for marginal distribution difference in the source
\item To correct for conditional distribution difference in the source
\item To correct both the marginal and conditional distribution in the source
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Information Transfer - What is being transferred}
Instances
\begin{enumerate}
\item Instance are re-weighted to correct for marginal distribution differences
\item The reweighted instances are directly used  in the target domain
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Information Transfer - What is being transferred}
Features - First Approach
\begin{enumerate}
\item Transform the features of source 
\item Reweight the features so that they more closely match the target domain
\item Above process also referred to as \textit{asymmetric feature transformation}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Information Transfer - What is being transferred}
Features - Second Approach
\begin{enumerate}
\item Discover underlying meaningful structures between domains to find a common latent feature space that has predictive qualities
\item Reduce the marginal distribution between the domains at the same time
\item Above approach - \textit{symmetric feature transformation}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Information Transfer - What is being transferred}
Parameters
\begin{enumerate}
\item Transfer knowledge through shared parameters of source and target domain learner models or 
\item Create multiple source learner models and optimally combine the reweighted learners to improve the target learner
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Neural Networks and Transfer Learning}
\begin{enumerate}
\item NNs are the majority algorithms to perform Transfer learning. 
\item Key aspects to be considered are as follows
\begin{itemize}
\item How can we tailor deep neural networks for transfer learning ?
\item How transfer learning performs with reusing layers and with different types of data
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Neural Networks and Transfer Learning}
\begin{enumerate}
\item NNs gain knowledge from the data it is trained on
\item Knowledge gets compiled as weights
\item Weights can be extracted and then transferred to any other neural network
\item So, no need to train NN from scratch
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Neural Networks and Transfer Learning}
Ways to fine tune the Neural Network model
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textit{Feature Extractor: } remove output layer of neural network and then use entire network as a fixed feature extractor
\item Use \textit{entire} architecture, \textit{initialize weight randomly} and train the model
\item Retrain some layers while freeze others: keep weights of initial layers as constant and modify only the higher layers
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}



\begin{frame}{Trends and Challenges}
\begin{enumerate}

\item \textit{Knowledge gain} when doing transfer learning and its quantification
\item \textit{Impact} of different datasets (target problems) on learning rates
\item \textit{Benchmark} available methods 
\item \textit{Unification} of Transfer Learning due to vast amount of formulations available
\item Public competition for \textit{benchmarking} learning algorithms
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Trends and Challenges}
Dissimilar Datasets
\begin{enumerate}
\item Quality of Kullback divergence measured on the datasets with different source/target problems
\item TL need to be more robust for \textit{heterogenous} problems
\item Problem gets severe when data features are not \textit{representative}
\item \textit{Big Data} calls for rapid development of TL algorithms
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}


\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{main}


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I have removed the `biblatex` tag since you do not use `biblatex`. You are BibTeX's `.bst` styles. The general setup looks OK to me, but we will only be able to check that thoroughly if you provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).

Comment: I could be wrong, but if the bibliography isn't inside a `frame` environment, I don't think it'll get used. It certainly wouldn't be visible in a presentation.

Answer (score 2):

To get a bibliography shown in class `beamer` you need to use the following code (see the added `frame`!):

```
\begin{frame}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{frame}
```

I shortend your given code and added the missing `frame` to the following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{Berkeley}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%\usepackage{graphicx} % not needed, loaded by class

\author{Upendra Pratap Singh}
\title{Transfer Learning}
%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\insertlogo}
%\setbeamercovered{transparent} 
%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
\logo{\includegraphics[height=1.6cm]{example-image-a}} % logo.png
\institute{Indian Institute of Information Technology, Allahabad} 
\date{\today} 

\subject{Data Analytics and Machine Learning} 
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

with the resulting bibliography page:

[image: resulting pdf page]